# Invalid Keystore Format - Signing Android APK in Azure DevOps build pipeline

Tags: xamarin.android, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, signing, android-keystore

I have a Xamarin Android application that I want to generate a signed APK for using the Azure DevOps build pipeline.

Right now, I receive `a java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format`.

I generated the keystore file from the command line with the following command:

```
keytool.exe -genkeypair -v -keystore myAppName.keystore -alias myAppNamekey -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

This keystore works on my local device.

I also tried adding the default debug.keystore file to the azure pipeline, and that works successfully.

I added the key to my (already working) CI build pipeline in Azure DevOps, under the "Signing and Aligning" section.

When it reaches this section, I receive the following error:

> Failed to load signer "signer #1" java.io.IOException: Invalid
>   keystore format
>   [error]Error: The process 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\24.0.3\apksigner.bat' failed
>   with exit code 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found a solution to this. But I changed two things so it could be either of these things.

1. I had a '!' in my keystore password. I removed that because I saw that their where issues with having special characters. (This is probably not the change that fixed it but I wanted to add this just to be sure)
2. I re-generated a key with jdk1.8.0_13 version. This is path to the keytool I used "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\bin\keytool.exe"

When doing these two things the signing task worked. Hope this helps!

Comment: That was it - the password can has a very narrow range of permissible characters. Thank you!

Comment: I had the same problem - I also had a ! in my pw, and changing the password fixed it. You can change the password to an existing keystore by running this command and following the prompts:

keytool -storepasswd -keystore /path/to/keystore

Answer (score 0):

Here was my problem - DevOps was finding the JDK in this folder:

C:\Program Files\Eclipse Foundation\jdk-8.0.302.8-hotspot\

while I was creating my keystore files with standard JDK (and then I tried Open JDK).

Once I created the keystore with the same JDK that DevOps was finding, it worked.

How did I find out which JDK it was finding? Xamarin.Android build task writes out w